# Image size breaks responsiveness

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I’m working on a website for my business at the moment.

I’m pretty much done, but the header (inside the main but before the content div) image isn’t resizing when on mobile, meaning that the user can scroll horizontally and it totally breaks the responsiveness.

Code at https://GitHub.com/Maestoso-Digital/MaestosoWebsite, and website at https://maestoso.uk.

How can I fix this?

On a less technical side, what are your thoughts on the design? Are there any changes you would recommend making?

I’m fairly new to web design and CSS in general, so sorry if this is really basic or the design looks a bit amateurish - we’ve all got to start somewhere

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the background is an `img` and not an actual `background-image` or even a `background`, set the `display` to block and give it a width of 100% so that the image will resize with a width of 100% based on the screen width

```
#header-img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you're looking for feedback and suggestions for the site, head over to [ux.stackexchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) you'll have more luck there